# How to set a listener on a span element in Polymer 2.0?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I have the following code

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
Polymer.dom(span).setAttribute('class','right-icon dfw-remove-icon dfw-24');
this.listen(span, 'tap', '_removeIt');
return span;
```

This segment of code is from an older project that uses Polymer 1 but I'm trying to make an application using Polymer 2. The third line doesn't work for me on Chrome, it gives me an error saying this.listen is not a function. How would I set a listener on the span element so that it triggers _removeIt() when clicked on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `this.listen` equvialent

`this.listen()` effectively calls `addEventListener()`, so the equivalent of:

```
this.listen(span, 'tap', '_removeIt');
```

is:

```
span.addEventListener('tap', e => this._removeIt(e));
```

#### Use `click` instead of `tap`

In Polymer 1, `tap` was recommended for cross-platform consistency in handling clicks/taps. However, in Polymer 2, [`tap` is no longer recommended as the default](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/gesture-events), given the advances of modern mobile browsers. You should use `click` instead of `tap`.

#### Don't do `Polymer.dom(span)`

There's no need to call `Polymer.dom(span)` if span is an element created with `document.createElement()`.

Comment: @JvalantDave No problem :)